# Datatables Enable/disable column sorting when click on table header span

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-modal

following some suggestions on related questions, I was able to unbind and bind again the default column sorting event.

But ended in a strange sorting behavior, when there are one or more hidden columns.

Desired behaviour:

I have a span inside a TH of a Databales column, that has to open a bootstrap-modal with remote url. but I don't want the sorting default event to be triggered, so onClick of the span I have placed this:`$('th').off('click.DT');` 
then I have this handler that fires the modal , and then binds the order listening again with no problem: `

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(){
        $($(this).data("target")+' .modal-body').load($(this).data("remote"));
            table.columns().every( function (i) {               
             if(table.columns().visible()[i]){
                table.order.listener( $('#Testata th:eq('+i+')'), i);
             }
            });
    });`
```

the problem arises when there are hidden columns:
with one hidden column i.e.: `

```
'columnDefs': [          
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false
            }]`
```

the order listener works on all columns but the sorting is wrong.
with more then one hidden columns i.e.: `

```
'columnDefs': [          
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [3],
                "visible": false
            }
        ]`
```

the order listener works NOT on all columns and the sorting is wrong.

Here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__jony__/qja8xepy/) to simulate the scenario please click on the (i) span on the first column.

thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a different running number that counts only the visible columns:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(){
    $($(this).data("target")+' .modal-body').load($(this).data("remote"));
    var elIdx = 0;
    table.columns(':visible').every( function (i) {
        table.order.listener( $('#Testata th:eq('+elIdx+')'), i);
        elIdx++;
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30egLrsw/)